# Can projective Hypersurfaces of different degrees be isomorphic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces

Say I have 2 Hypersurfaces $S,S'\subset \mathbb{P}_k^3$ with different degrees and $k$ a field. Can it happen that the two Hypersurfaces are isomorphic or can they be fully distinguished by their degree?
I have the feeling that the degree should be an invariant even for non smooth and non integral Hypersurfaces and I think there is some proof using Serre-Duality or Riemann-Roch, but I can't get the details right.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Consider the canonical bundle.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a (fairly) elementary argument for the nonsingular case: let a degree $d$ hypersurface $i:S\hookrightarrow \Bbb{P}^3$ be given. There is a short exact sequence:
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{P}^3}(-d)\to \mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{P}^3} \to i_*\mathcal{O}_S\to 0.
$$
By the adjunction formula, $\omega_S = \mathcal{O}_S(d-4)$ and so twisting by $d-4$ gives
$$
0\to \mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{P}^3}(-4)\to \mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{P}^3}(d-4)\to i_*\omega_S\to 0.
$$
The long exact sequence of cohomology yields
$$
0\to H^0(\Bbb{P}^3,\omega_{\Bbb{P}^3})\to H^0(\Bbb{P}^3,\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{P}^3}(d-4))\to H^0(S,\omega_S)\to H^1(\Bbb{P}^3,\omega_{\Bbb{P}^3}).
$$
In particular, $h^0(\Bbb{P}^3,\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{P}^3}(d-4)) = g(S)$. This completely distinguishes hypersurfaces of degree $d\ge 4$. The remaining case is when $1\le d\le 3$ for both $S$ and $S'$. Now, the $d=1$ case gives $\Bbb{P}^2$, the $d=2$ case gives a quadric which is isomorphic to $\Bbb{P}^1\times \Bbb{P}^1$. For $d=3$, any cubic in $\Bbb{P}^3$ is a blowup of $\Bbb{P}^2$ at exactly $6$ points. This distinguishes it from the other low degree cases (for instance, consider the rank of the Picard group).

As for the singular case, I'm not completely sure. Probably something can be said with more attention.

Comment: You get this description of $\omega_{S}$ via the adjunction formula, but doesn't this only work in the smooth case? How would you describe $\omega$ for a non-smooth divisor $S$?

Comment: Indeed, I noted at the beginning that this is just for smooth varieties. If you want to deal with the singular case, you can explicitly compute the canonical sheaf of a complete intersection (see Hartshorne III section 7 for instance).